# Converting to JSon or any map type java

Tags: java, json

I have a string which looks like below.

```
Model [Name=Mobie , location= US, actualTransferDate=null, scanserialCode=234335,1237787, modelNum=MIC 898989 ]
```

Can i convert this to Json? Is it possible?So i have done like this below but it not working now.

```
List<String> invoicelist = Arrays.asList(checkeditems);
    String invocejson = new Gson().toJson(invoicelist);
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        map = mapper.readValue(invocejson, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>(){});
        log.info("****"+map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If i can convert it could be easy for me to pass json to Jsp and then use it there.Can any one help me on this?

Comment: What output do you want to get? You're hardly going to convert that string to JSON, right? You'd have to **parse** it and then **generate** JSON. And I don't see any attempt to do it in your code. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, i am going to convert that list of string to json. Each string in that list looks like which i posted in the message. If i can convert this to json then it would be easy for me to show in table with jsp and jstl.

Comment: What would you like the final JSON string to look like?

Comment: Well, I attempted to write some quick dirty solution, just for fun, but then I saw that list (multiple values being assigned to one key). You'll need to write a full parser for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this....

```
        //import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String model = "Model [Name=Mobie , location= US , actualTransferDate=null , scanserialCode=234335,1237787 , modelNum=MIC 898989 ]";
    String[] v = model.substring(5).replace("[" , "").replace("]" , "").split(" ,");
    for(int i = 0;i < v.length;i++){
        String[] j = v[i].split("=");
        switch (j[0]) {
        case " Name":
            object.put("Name",j[1]);
            break;
        case " location":
            object.put("location", "US");
            break;
        case " actualTransferDate":
            object.put("actualTransferDate",j[1]);
            break;
        case " scanserialCode":
            String[] l = j[1].split(",");
            array.add(Integer.parseInt(l[0]));
            array.add(Integer.parseInt(l[1]));
            object.put("scanserialCode", array);
            break;
        case " modelNum":
            object.put("modelNum",j[1]);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("JSON Output string : "+object);
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

> JSON Output string :
>   {"Name":"Mobie","actualTransferDate":"null","location":"US","modelNum":"MIC
>   898989 ","scanserialCode":[234335,1237787]}

Comment: I am getting list of string(showed in the question)from my jsp which i need to send back to another jsp to display in table. Your solution will not work in my case.

Comment: My solution will work only if the key value pairs in string are " ," i.e. space+comma separated, and multiple values to key should be "," i.e. comma separated.... my answer is just a hint to solution you might have to make some changes to it